# embed area51 proposals

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, site-proposal

Lots of Proposals in hierarchy ! Just a single Stream & dividing in branches, I think generate a crowd of SO like sites !

SO is general for Software Developers. But, there are many proposals gathering on area51, many of them having subset of general proposals. As an example, different types of Engineering/Science in a common proposal of Engineering/Science.

or I think there should be some facility to embed proposals for moderators which automatically transfers the followers in between as well !

I don't know I am correct with this idea or not. Please share your views with this Idea !

Answer (score 3):

There are heaps of Sport type ones there. So to overcome it I made one just called Sports hopping that It will be full of people on othere spot ones but now we have only 6 people.

I was hoping that there called merge it.